# Align two tables horizontally HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two tables that align horizontally using this syntax:

```
<table width=100%>
  <tr>
    <td><table1 code goes here>
    </td>
    <td><table2 code goes here>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is all fine and dandy and they align if the tables have the same number of data rows. But if one has fewer than the other, then they are still aligned in the same positions, but the other table is shrunk, so they look like:

```
header
data
data
data    header
data    data
data    data
data    data
data
data
```

Is there any way to getthem to align from the top down, as well?

Like

```
header    header
data      data
data      data
data      data
data
data
data
data
data
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In your example code you have only one table even though you say that table 1 code goes here and table 2 code goes here, that's all within one table.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `valign = top`.

```
<table width=100%> 
  <tr> 
    <td valign="top"><table1 code goes here>
    </td>
    <td valign="top"><table2 code goes here>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeap exactly what I was doing! Thanks @Tricky12!

Comment: You beat me to the answer, so I figured I'd pitch in :-)

Comment: No worries @user3979986 ! It would be better if you use CSS for doing that kind of things. Also another way would be of having 2 divs in the same line and put the tables inside each div.

Comment: Thank You :-) Help me a lot

Comment: The `valign` attribute is no longer supported in HTML5; CSS styling using `float:left` is a more appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display: inline-block;` for each table if using CSS

Else you can add  `<td valign="top">` for both tables in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `<td valign="top">` will solve your problem for sure. This tag vertically aligns the contents from the top making it stick to the top line.

Similarly you can also use some other values for valign as per your needs.
They are:

1. `baseline`
2. `middle`
3. `bottom`